# SAS Global date comparison

Tags: sas

I'm trying to do a date comparison but I'm not getting the correct results. Does anyone know what's going on?

```
%macro ttt;
    %let check_start = 28APR2014;
    %if "&check_start."d < "25may2014"d %then %let true = 1;
    %else %if "&check_start."d > "25may2014"d %then %let true = 2;
    %put &true;
%mend;
%ttt;

14         %macro ttt;
15          %let check_start = 28APR2010;
16          %if "&check_start."d < "25may2014"d %then %let true = 1;
17          %else %if "&check_start."d > "25may2014"d %then %let true = 2;
18          %put &true;
19          %mend;
20          %ttt;
true = 2
```

Macro-variable true should equal 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use %sysevalf() to evaluate the comparison in this case. The following works.

```
%macro ttt;
    %let check_start = 28APR2015;
    %if %sysevalf("&check_start"d < '25may2014'd) %then %let true=1;
    %else %if %sysevalf("&check_start."d > '25may2014'd) %then %let true=2;
    %put &true.;
%mend;
%ttt;
```

Comment: Ugh.  I didn't realize %sysevalf() can handle date literals.  Good to know.  Thanks @Reeza.

Answer (score 2):

Reeza has provided a good solution but I thought I'd add a few suggestions as well.

The problem you are having is the reason I recommend never using date literals when working in the macro language.  Instead, of date literals (i.e. `"01jan2000"d`) I recommend using macro variables that contain date values (i.e. `%let start_of_21st_century = %sysfunc(mdy(1,1,2000));` ).  By using macro variables, not only do you avoid your above issue, but you also get the benefit of being able to self-document your code.

Currently I have no idea what significance the 25th May 2014 has in your code, but if you had this line:

```
%let product_launch_date = %sysfunc(mdy(5,25,2014));
```

... then it would be clear to anyone reading it what the significance is.

Your code would then become:

```
%macro ttt;
    %local check_start compare_date;

    %let check_start = %sysfunc(mdy(4,28,2014));
    %let compare_date = %sysfunc(mdy(5,25,2014));

    %if &check_start < &compare_date %then %let true = 1;
    %else %if &check_start > &compare_date %then %let true = 2;

    %put &true;
%mend;
```

There's still a few more things I'd consider changing.  One thing I noticed is that if the 2 date values are equal, than `true` will not be assigned a value.  So that should probably be remedied.

Also, in SAS, the typical concept of true/false is typically represented as follows:

- A value of zero represents FALSE
- Any non-zero number (including negatives) represents TRUE

So having a macro variable named `true` with either a value of 1 or 2 (both values would normally represent a value of true) may be confusing to some.  I'd consider either renaming the macro variable, or using values of 0, and 1 (or other non-zero number).

Incorporating all of this, the macro would become something like:

```
%macro check_dates;
    %local check_start compare_date;

    %let check_start = %sysfunc(mdy(4,28,2014));
    %let compare_date = %sysfunc(mdy(5,25,2014));

    %let check_start_compared_higher = &check_start > &compare_date;

    %if &check_start_compared_higher %then %do;
      %put It was higher =) ;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      %put It was equal to or lower =( ;
    %end;
%mend;
%check_dates;
```

A few comments on the final macro... The macro variable named `true` has been replaced with a more descriptive variable named `check_start_compared_higher`.  Because we just need a boolean value stored in it, we can simply assigning it the result of evaluating the expression `&check_start > &compare_date` which will return either a 0 (if false) or a 1 (if true).  This is easier to read than using `%if...%else...` statements to do an assignment, as it is immediately clear that the line of code is simply performing an assignment and nothing more.

The line `%if &check_start_compared_higher %then %do;` shows how we can use the newly saved value to control program flow.  Because the value in `&check_start_compared_higher` resolves to either TRUE or FALSE we can easily use it this way to make easy-to-read if-statements.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks!