# SAS Macro date inequalities

Tags: date, sas

Good morning,

This is a similar question to this one ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932269/sas-global-date-comparison/31932700)) but I am ideally looking for further explanation that I cannot find anywhere.

I was recently asked by a colleague why the the following inequalities return the results that they do:

```
%MACRO  TEST ;

%IF '01JAN2009'D    <   '01MAR2015'D    %THEN %PUT  1 is True ;
%ELSE %PUT  1 is False ;

%IF '01FEB2009'D    <   '01MAR2015'D    %THEN %PUT  2 is True ;
%ELSE %PUT  2 is False ;

%IF '01SEP2009'D    <   '01MAR2015'D    %THEN %PUT  3 is True ;
%ELSE %PUT  3 is False ;

%IF '01OCT2009'D    <   '01MAR2015'D    %THEN %PUT  4 is True ;
%ELSE %PUT  4 is False ;

%MEND   TEST ;
%TEST ;
```

Running TEST returns:

```
1 is True
2 is True
3 is False
4 is False
```

I understand that %SYSEVALF() is required to resolve these inequalities as expected.  However can anyone explain to me what SAS is doing in these four instances and why two return TRUE values, whilst two return FALSE?

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform date-literal evaluations directly in SAS MACRO. In your examples above, the evaluations are being performed as character strings, hence `'01SEP2009'D < '01MAR2015'D` being false as `01S` is greater than `01M`.

To compare date literals, you need to convert them to the underlying SAS date (i.e. a number).

```
  %PUT %EVAL(%SYSEVALF('01sep2009'd) < %SYSEVALF('01mar2015'd)) ;
  /* log shows 1 (true) */
```

Answer (score 1):

It is comparing them as strings.  The results are explained by the fact that `J` and `F` come before `M` and `S` and `O` come after it.